# OpenCV: Reading image series from a folder

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, video-capture, video-processing

I am trying to read a series of images from a folder using OpenCV's `VideoCapture` function. After some search on the internet, my current code is like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap ( "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Images\\%02d.jpg");
```

I was expecting to see that `VideoCapture` function should read all the images in that folder with names of two serial digits, like `01.jpg, 02.jpg, ..., 30.jpg`. Someone told on the internet that the `VideoCapture` function should be ale to catch all of these images once I give the first image's location and name. So I also tried to do it like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap ("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Images\\01.jpg");
```

But still this is not working, at least not for my case here. These images are of different sizes, so I am going to read them first, resize them, and then do further processing on each of them. How can I do this? I am using Windows7, with VisualStudio. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "not working"? does it read some images and crash at some point? Do you getr an error ?

Comment: It gives me this error: 'Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:529)'.

Comment: it gives this error for te first file of the list right ?

Comment: That is true. Even if I changed the part '01.jpg' to '%2d.jpg' it still gives this error.

Comment: By the way, I've included all the necessary '.dll' files for my project, even copied all of them in the project directory. So I don't think this is an error of 'missing dll files'. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have never tried to use cv::VideoCapture to open images... Sorry.
have you tried (just out of curiosity) to do the same thing with different dormats of images (png, bmp...) ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30489/discussion-between-quentin-geissmann-and-king-knight)

Comment: Breaking down a problem can make debugging simpler.  You should first try opening one of the images as an individual image using `imread`.  That will allow you to establish whether OpenCV has access to the file.  If that fails, you know that the problem is with the specified path (incorrect format, non-existing file, etc).  If it works, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I've done it, and it worked fine for single image. But when I tried to read the series in a folder, it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experiences the VideoCapture can read a sequence of images even without specifing the format.
E.g. the following works fine:

```
std::string pathToData("cap_00000000.bmp");
cv::VideoCapture sequence(pathToData);
```

the images are sequentially read:

```
Mat image;
sequence >> image; // Reads cap_00000001.bmp
```

**HOWEVER:** This only works if the images are located within the folder of the executable file. I could not figure out to specify a directory like this:

```
std::string pathToData("c:\\path\\cap_00000000.bmp");
std::string pathToData("c://path//cap_00000000.bmp");
// etc.
```

Seems to be a bug. An offical example can be found here:

http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/reading-image-sequences-with-opencv/
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/823/files

Answer (score 4):

According to [this link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/317/how-to-read-directory-with-images-by-videocapture/) it needs to be:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Images/%2d.jpg");
                      ^^^                             ^^^
```

i.e. just a single `:` after the `C` and `%2d` for a 2 digit file name sequence.

Similarly your second example should probably be:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Images/01.jpg");
                      ^^^
```

Comment: What have you tried, specifically - did you fix *both* problems in the first example above ? Did you try the second example ?

Comment: For the double ':', actually it was my typo, sorry for that. In my code, I used only one single ':' actually. But seems like this is not the reason for the error. I've edited this mistake in my question.

Answer (score 1):

use glob as in glob(folderpath, vectorOfimages)
then access each of the images as vectorOfimages[i].

vectorOfimages is

```
 vector<String>
```

and folderpath is a String.

Answer (score 0):

We need to declare like this

```
VideoCapture vcap("C:\\pathDirectory\\folderName\\drop%d.bmp");
```

I declared like that and it worked fine for me, because my images names were drop1.bmp, drop2.bmp, drop3.bmp ……and so on