# Bad flag error in OpenCV after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' . Unsupported array type in cvGetMat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new to OpenCV , and trying to read the sequence of images in a folder. My code is as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


   void loadImage(Mat image,int number)
    {
      char filename[100];
       strcpy(filename, "/home/folder1/imagefolder/");

     char frameNo[10];
       sprintf(frameNo, "%08i", number); 
       strcat(filename, frameNo);
       strcat(filename, ".png");
       cout<< filename;

       image = imread(filename);
       if (image.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
    {
    cout << "Error : Image not loaded." << endl;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
     Mat image;
     int nImages=8;
     for (int i = 1; i < nImages; i++)
    {
     loadImage(image,i);
     namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     imshow( "Display Image", image );
     waitKey(100000);
     return 0;

    }
    }
```

It gets compiled, But on running the executable, it gives following error:

OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /home/vuadmin/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/vuadmin/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
Aborted (core dumped)

Please help me find out the error.

I also tried out the other method as given in 
[OpenCV: Reading image series from a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713258/opencv-reading-image-series-from-a-folder)

but in my case it shows only the first image .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see several errors in your code :

your prototype  `void loadImage(Mat image,int number)` makes a copy of the cv::Mat image, so after the call of this function, `image` is empty. You should set the image by reference

```
void loadImage(Mat& image,int number)
```

in this case in  `imshow( "Display Image", image );` `image` argument may not be empty. that may cause your openCV error

One other thing in your entry point of your program, you make a `return 0;` inside your loop, so the program exit with code value 0 on the first iteration. Put the return after the loop. Btw, you should "open" your window once, and not on each iteration, but i don't think this causes any error.

```
 int main()
    {
     Mat image;
     int nImages=8;
     namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     for (int i = 1; i < nImages; i++)
      {
        loadImage(image,i);
        imshow( "Display Image", image );
        waitKey(100000);

      }

     return 0;
    }
```

You must check the validity of your image after your call of `loadImage(image, i)` because inside your function, a error message is printed on the standard output, but in your loop, you don't make any check on the image

```
loadImage(image, i);
if ( ! image.empty ())
    imshow( "Display Image", image );
waitKey(100000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ! I did not change the return statement position, but yes the Mat Image created a pr0blem.....Need to brush up the basic c++ :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in Java with OpenCV. I realized that the problem wasn't the images or frames I was using, but the HaarCascade file. I would try different cascade files (you can find them on OpenCV website), both Haar Cascade files and LBP cascade files.

Hope that helps. Cheers