# Reading images in directory using VideoCapture not working

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am trying to read multiple image files named like 001.jpg, 002.jpg, 003.jpg and onwards by using OpenCV on **Linux** and displaying them in a window after some delay. Here is my code -

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    cv::VideoCapture cam("/home/bikz05/Desktop/dataset/%03d.jpg");
    if (!cam.isOpened())
        cout << "Capture is not opened";
    cv::Mat image;
    const string Window = "Image Number";
    namedWindow(Window, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    while(true) {
        cam >> image;
        if (!image.data) {
            std::cout << "Preview Ends" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        cv::imshow(Window, image);
        waitKey(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the first line of the main function, I even tried using

```
cv::VideoCapture cam("/home/bikz05/Desktop/dataset/001.jpg");
```

I even tried to place the images in the same folder as the binary, even that didn't help.

In both the cases, it displays only the first image and then the program exits. Note, it doesn't finish.

P.S. - The answers provided on [Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713258/opencv-reading-image-series-from-a-folder) and [opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/question/317/how-to-read-directory-with-images-by-videocapture/) did not produce the intended result.

Comment: `VideoCapture` will try to store a frame in a `Mat` regardless of the `Mat`'s size, so when you store the first image, the `Mat` allocated to match the fist image size. Now all the other images in your directory should be the same size as the first one or smaller(if they are smaller it will look bad but should work). However if some of the images are larger than the first one `VideoCapture` simply cant store them in the same `Mat` allocated for the first image since its to small.

Comment: No, your reasoning is flawed. Before posting this question, I tried keeping 001.jpg and 002.jpg the same image. But the code didn't work.

Comment: try replasing `"/home/bikz05/Desktop/dataset/%03d.jpg"` to `"/home/bikz05/Desktop/dataset/%3d.jpg"`.

Comment: btw I think you can just write `"/home/bikz05/Desktop/dataset/%1d.jpg"` and it should read all the files named with 1 digit or more.

Comment: @DimaMaligin none of your above mentioned solutions work.

Comment: They do I just tried them and they work fine. My first comment is still valid so check that as well. And if it still fails I would say that karlphillip was right and its a permission issue.

Comment: I am able to read all the images using imread but not VideoCapture, then its not a permissions issue.  By the way, which OS are you testing the code? On Windows, these do work as in links I provided.

Comment: I am on windows. But this should work on linux as well. Here is a link on the issue from openCV site maybe youl find something. http://answers.opencv.org/question/317/how-to-read-directory-with-images-by-videocapture/

Comment: It's the same link I had posted. At no place it's mentioned that this works for linux. The only thing mentioned is wrt to proper name format convention.

Comment: Well I didn't read it though to the end. Buy why wont you use `imread()` as karlphillip suggested?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I wanted to try it this feature of VideoCapture class. I already know it to do otherwise.

Comment: I see, well in the link it did say that it is not officially supported yet. To tell the truth I don't know if it is supported on the newest version of openCV but if it is it still can be buggy. I'm on openCV 2.4.8 and it works O'k on Windows.

Comment: Yes, it is not there in the official documentation, but it is a very convenient way of reading files.

Answer (score 2):

The code as you have written has several problems, but if you are going to read images from the disk, use `cv::imread()` instead of `cv::VideoCapture`:

```
std::string filename = "/home/bikz05/Desktop/dataset/001.jpg";
const std::string Window = "Image Number";
cv::namedWindow(Window, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
while (true) 
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(filename.c_str());
    if (!image.data) 
    {
        std::cout << "!!! File not found: " << filename << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    cv::imshow(Window, image);
    cv::waitKey(1000);

    // And before the loop ends, update filename with the next image:
    // filename = ???;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: I do know how to read it with imread, but I wanted to do it with VideoCapture. I could have had done it with some other method also but I wanted to do it using VideoCapture. By the way, what are the problems with the code?

Comment: If `cam.isOpened()` fails, **return**. Create `image` inside the loop, not outside. Make sure the user has permission to read the files in that location. Make sure all the files have the same extension and also have the same naming scheme.

Comment: For sake of brevity, I had truncated alot of the code, there was a return statement earlier. It's not a issue of permissions. I am able to display the first image and then the program exits.

Comment: **Create `image` inside the loop, not outside.** This is my last message to you.

Comment: Then go with the approach I suggested, it's easier to debug and figure out the problem. I don't know what version of OpenCV you are using, but maybe it's a bug on `VideoCapture`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use glob as in `glob(folderpath, vectorOfimages)` then access each of the images as `vectorOfimages[i]`.

vectorOfimages is

```
 vector<String>
```

and folderpath is a String.

I had the same problem and `videoCapture` does not solve it.